# Is it proper for a Muslim to have a non-Muslim Facebook name?

Tags: sharia

Assalamualaikum. I am curious about if it is ok for a Muslim girl like me to have a non-Muslim Facebook name? It combines Japanese and English and the first name just means "blossom". All my friends know it is me but lately I have been thinking that I ma being recognized solely by that name since it's what everyone is seeing. I heard it is not a problem if it has a good meaning? Is it necessary for me to make it clear on Facebook to others that I am a Muslim (my picture is an illustration of a girl in hijab though)? Your help is appreciated, JazakAllah.

Comment: Related: [***Islam forbids bad nicknames! What if people keep their own?***](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/128/59)

Answer (score 3):

Wa alaikom assalam.
There is no such thing as Msulim name or non-Muslim name. It will depend on what the name means.